# Missing data in truth table and commenting on missing value

Tags: truth-table

I was trying to solve the attached question from the book *Digital Design: With an Introduction to Verilog HDL, 5e* however the values of f1 and f2 for the entry (1,1,0) are missing.

[image: Question]

If we use sum of product or product of sum form the function we get would be valid for all the values however it would also give a result for (1,1,0).

Will that value be the missing value from the table?

I tried both POS and SOP and the result for 1,1,0 is 0 in both the cases so is it correct to say the original truth table must have had 0 for the following entry or do we not talk about it since it was not one of the readings which we had.

(Note: I have no idea about K Maps just yet so please refrain from using those to explain unless that's the only way.)

Comment: I really encourage learning how to use karnaugh maps, they make things *very* easy.

Comment: Yeah i started watching their tutorials they'll be covered later in course, this exercise wasn't supposed to be done using K Maps so I wanted a way to interpret the results with Boolean Algebra @Hearth

Answer (score 1):

K-maps really are the easiest.

Outputs f1 and f2 are X for 110, so they can be 1 or 0 in answer.  So in boolean algebra, 110 can be added or excluded as required.

$$f_1 = \bar a \bar b \bar c + \bar a b \bar c + \bar a b c  + a \bar b \bar c + abc$$

You have \$ab \bar c\$ as a don't care.  So looking at the inputs of your don't care you have a & b at 1 and c at 0.  You look for other common terms in your function.  There are three \$\bar c\$, so there may be an advantage to add it.

$$f_1 = \bar a \bar b \bar c + \bar a b \bar c + \bar a b c  + a \bar b \bar c + abc + ab \bar c$$

Extract common factor \$\bar c\$.

$$f_1 = \bar c (\bar a \bar b  + \bar a b + a \bar b + ab) + \bar a b c  + abc$$
$$f_1 = \bar c (\bar a (\bar b  + b) + a (\bar b + b)) + \bar a b c  + abc$$
$$f_1 = \bar c (\bar a + a) + \bar a b c  + abc$$
$$f_1 = \bar c + \bar a b c  + abc$$

So 3 terms and a don't care became 1 term.

I excluded \$\bar a b c  + abc\$ from the reduction, but a similar process is required for them. Go back to origional function and see if they can be reduced.

Partial K-map:

[image]

I have solved for half of f1.  You have to finish it, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so would it be appropriate to say a TLDR of the answer is it doesn't really matter as anyways the term is going to disappear when you use reductions? So it can be both 0 or 1 whichever one wants?

Comment: Yes.  A 1 or 0, but it cannot be both for one function.  110 is 1 for f1.  It can be 1 or 0 for f2.  Work through it and edit your answer putting in your answers.  Someone will confirm it, but we don't do the work for you.  A nudge in general direction is all I've done.

Comment: Got it thanks :)